# Delete Rows which contains certain strings in Excel VBA / Macro

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, wildcard

The following is an extract of my code. All of them function perfectly, which allows me to delete the row when the cell under column H contains "CHARGES, BANK CHARGES, AMENDMENT CHARGES". However, what concerns me is that I want to delete every row when the cell under column H contains "XXX CHARGES". The code looks stupid now because there can be unlimited kinds of charges (e.g. BANK CHARGES, AMENDMENT CHARGES, xxx CHARGES, yyy CHARGES). But the rule is that there must be certain strings before "CHARGES". So, my question is how do I perfect the code by using wildcard (e.g. *) and formulas (e.g. Left, Mid, Right)?
Many thanks for your help.

```
Dim c3 As Range, DeleteRange3 As Range, DataRange3 As Range
Dim LR3 As Long 'last row
Dim StartString3 As String
Dim StartString3b As String
Dim StartString3c As String

'change sheet name as required
With Worksheets("OutPayments")
    'find last row in range
    LR3 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row

    'range you are searching
    Set DataRange3 = .Range("H2:H" & LR3)
End With

StartString3 = "CHARGES"
StartString3b = "BANK CHARGES"
StartString3c = "AMENDMENT CHARGES"


DataRange3.EntireRow.Hidden = False

For Each c3 In DataRange3.Cells
        If Right(c3.Value, 7) = StartString3 Or Left(c3.Value, 12) = StartString3b Or Left(c3.Value, 17) = StartString3c Or Left(c3.Value, 13) = "SWIFT CHARGES" Then
            If DeleteRange3 Is Nothing Then
                Set DeleteRange3 = c3
            Else
                Set DeleteRange3 = Union(DeleteRange3, c3)
            End If
        End If
    Next c3
    'delete all matched rows in one go
    If Not DeleteRange3 Is Nothing Then DeleteRange3.EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: Use the word `Like` in replace of `=`...

Comment: You may shorten your if condition to: If c3.Value Like "*CHARGES" Then...